# How do I serve a Flask app using HttpPlatformHandler?

Tags: iis, python, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to use the HttpPlatformHandler module in IIS on Windows Server 2016 to serve a basic application written in Python using Flask. The Python environment is managed using `pipenv`, and the Flask app is just a basic "Hello World" at the moment. Here's my `web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
            <add name="Flask" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform processPath="C:\Users\dummyuser\.virtualenvs\inventory-z_DIyVzW\Scripts\flask.exe" arguments="run --port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" stdoutLogEnabled="true">
            <environmentVariables>
                <environmentVariable name="FLASK_APP" value="hello.py" />
                <environmentVariable name="PYTHONPATH" value="S:\Web\inventory" />
            </environmentVariables>
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The application runs fine if I launch it from the command line and access it directly, but when I try to get at it through IIS it just stalls and I never see any output. The log files generally look like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\dummyuser\.virtualenvs\inventory-z_DIyVzW\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

How can I get IIS to launch and serve up this application?

(In researching this issue, I found several suggestions to use a WSGI server like Waitress, but I was under the impression that using HttpPlatformHandler instead of the FastCGI method meant that a WSGI server wasn't necessary. Am I misunderstanding the interaction here?)

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2017/09/01/running-flask-app-with-httpplatformhandler-in-azure-app-serviceswindows/